# SyncFusion Asp.Net Core ej-grid currency formatting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, syncfusion

In SyncFusion's Asp.Net Core ej-grid, I have a column like this:

```
<e-column field="ValueChange" header-text="Value Change" width="90" format="{0:C}"></e-column>
```

It prints out negative currency as ($1200.00). My PC is set to -$1200.00, but that doesn't seem to be respected. I've tried overriding CurrentCulture to set the negative currency format, but that's ignored too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you would like to set the negative currency format in grid. To achieve your requirement please set the negative sign in format property of columns in grid.

Refer the code example.

```
  <e-column field="ValueChange" header-text="Value Change" width="90" format="-{0:C}"></e-column>
```